# Как сделать обновление столбцов в таблице бд в уже созданной записи?

Tags: php, база-данных, функции, phpmyadmin, update

Всем доброго времени суток! В общем, ситуация следующая. У меня есть форма, с которой происходит добавление пользователя в бд. Есть 3 таблицы, куда идут записи после нажатия кнопки "добавить". Проблема в том, что у меня обновление столбцов "status" и "image" для всех уже созданных пользователей, а должно только для последнего созданного пользователя. Я приложил скриншот того, что происходит в бд при выполнения кода, который ниже. Скорее всего проблема с записью WHERE id = ... Однако, пока не догадался как сделать, чтобы все-таки запись шла к конкретному пользователю, возможно можно сделать по id для конкретного пользователя. Заранее спасибо!

```html
function set_status($status)
{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=array;dbname=my_project;", "root", "");
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET status = :status WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(:id)";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result = $statement->execute(["status" => $status]);
}

function add_image($image)
{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=array;dbname=my_project;", "root", "");
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET image = :image WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(:id)";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result = $statement->execute(["image" => $image]);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: передавайте `id` так же как и статус

Comment: И откуда бы `id` возьмется в этих методах?

Comment: id передается в функции по добавлению пользователя

function add_user($email, $password)
{
 $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=array;dbname=my_project;", "root", "");
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, role, status, image) VALUES (:email, :password, '', '', '')";
 $passwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $final = $statement->execute(["email" => $email, "password" => $passwd]);
 return $pdo->lastInsertId();
}